# Check visibility or status change of a window

Tags: c++11, process, window, visibility

I have to enumerate all process running on my machine and notify if some changement will happen (for example: change of visibility of windows, open a new window, close a window).
To enumerate all processes I can use this function provided by MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682623(v=vs.85).aspx
I thought that I need to save a list of running processes and check (how without polling?) if it changes. Can I do it without saving current running processes?
For the visibility changes here https://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/windows/desktop/ms646274(v=vs.85).aspx I found that `VM_ACTIVATE`  message is sent to both windows. How can I catch it? Can I do it in another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whom is interested in this topic, I found that to check if a window is created or destroyed I've to use `SetWinEventHook()`, like in the [example of its MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx). I simply check if `event` value is `EVENT_OBJECT_CREATE` or `EVENT_OBJECT_DESTROY`. For other events, check the [event constants list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066(v=vs.85).aspx).